# How to format SI units?

Tags: siunitx

> I get 1.0 Nm. But how to get 1.0 N.m

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{1.0}{\newton\meter}\\
1.0~N$\cdot$m
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`inter-unit-product` is an available option and described in [the documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx). To get correct spacing you should use `${}\cdot{}$`. However I prefer a tighter spacing by `$\cdot$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\SI[inter-unit-product =$\cdot$]{1.0}{\newton\meter}\\
\SI[inter-unit-product =${}\cdot{}$]{1.0}{\newton\meter}\\
$1.0\,\mathrm{N}\cdot\mathrm{m}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

To set his behavior for the whole document you can specify the option via `\sisetup`

```
\sisetup{inter-unit-product =$\cdot$}
```

Comment: I want this setting for whole document.

Comment: @sandu: `\sisetup{inter-unit-product =$\cdot$}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel One should use `\si[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]` to get the corrected spacing.

Comment: Setting this behaviour for the whole document directly at the package call is done without the math typesetting `$`-symbols: `\usepackage[inter-unit-product =\cdot]{siunitx}`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry for being late to the party. Could you explain how one can know what is the "correct" spacing for any situation? I find it hard to try answer some basic questions I have an resort to posting questions here because some people argue that approach B is better than approach A because it have "correct" spacing but I do not know what is the correct spacing for a given situation? Thanks in advance btw

Comment: @Jorayen Both newton and meter are units and `\cdot` is a math operator; therefore, I would say that it should be treated as such, i.e., the `\cdot` has to be in mathmode.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for the zombie reply, but aren't the units typeset in math mode? In that case:

```
\SI[inter-unit-product =$\cdot$]{1.0}{\newton\meter}
```

won't compile. You should use:

```
\SI[inter-unit-product =\ensuremath{\cdot}]{1.0}{\newton\meter}
```

instead.

Comment: This is already covered in the other answer (to some extent).

Comment: In the recent siunitx [major update](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2843.1621343877.4615.ctan-ann@ctan.org) from version 2 to version 3, the `\SI` command has changed to `\qty` command. And you can still use the old commands, the author says "Where possible, older names are mapped to newer ones internally: you will be warned in the log if this is the case."