# How to add a decimal point in the units of a concentration?

Tags: siunitx, chemistry

I have been writing my concentrations as per the code below using `\SI{300}{\milli\gram\per\milli\litre}` however my supervisor keeps writing a stupid . in all my feedback and wants the concentration to look like `mg.ml$^-1$`.

Everything I try writes the `.` as an accent on top of `\` or the units. Is it possible to replace the space between the mg and ml with a dot?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{300}{\milli\gram\per\milli\litre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is this answered by [How to format SI units?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59032/106162)

Comment: \sisetup{inter-unit-product=\mathord{\cdot}} \SI{300}{\milli\gram\per\milli\litre} solved the problem